# Is it possible to make a Google Photos style search bar?

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

In Google Photos, the toolbar is actually a search bar, and holds both the drawer's icon, and the search icon as well as functioning as a search bar. Any way that I can recreate this in my own app instead of using a standard toolbar? I can provide a screenshot if requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a appbar layout and add a edittext. if you want the toolbar to look like it is floating, specify the margin xml attribute.

Follow this guide, it will help you make decisions according to your use.
https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:margin="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <EditText ... />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

taken from: http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out :)

Comment: Please see my comment again, I found something more specific with a good base sample for you !

Answer (score 0):

Google uses "Material Design" (https://material.google.com/) concept, so search for "Material Design".

If you have an web project, consider https://getmdl.io/ or https://material.angularjs.org for example.

Comment: I know they use Material Design (as my app is using Material as well) but I wanna know how can I code this. I can't find how to make a search bar on Android anywhere besides using the normal toolbar and having a search icon in that, which I don't want.